# Reset Chart To Initial Load Throws renderTo Error

Tags: highcharts

Using latest HighStock/HighCharts we are creating charts with this syntax:

```
$('#container').highcharts({...
```

We then allow the user to do some manipulation of the chart series displayed. We added the ability for the user to reset the chart back to how it was originally. We are using this method:

```
function forceResetChart(chart) {
    var opts = chart.options;
    chart.destroy();
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opts);
}
```

This does reset the chart and we are able to make changes again. However, we are keep getting errors thrown in the console:

> TypeError: a.renderTo is undefined @ .../JavaScript/HighStock/highstock.js:198

How can we still use the cleaner syntax (`$('#container').highcharts({...`) and not get this error thrown?

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/5pa7N/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1) Just make sure you still specify "renderTo:'container'" in the chart properties.
Or, if you don't want to include in the initial chart code, add it to the options in your forceReset function.

option 2) in your forceReset function, use the same '$('#container').Highcharts...' syntax to call your chart, rather than switching back to the other syntax

```
example of option 2:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pa7N/8/

{{edit option 3:

- set options variable up front.
- call chart on page load using that variable.
- reload chart using that variable

http://jsfiddle.net/eYmh9/

Comment: How would I add it to the options in forceReset func?

Comment: I believe opts.chart.renderTo = 'container' should do it

Comment: I get that. but in my code I am doing `chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opts)`. Would I add the chart.renderTo after the fact?

Comment: between defining the opts variable and calling the highcharts function.  I also updated answer with an example for the 2nd option

Comment: This works once. Click on the destroy button again - you get the renderTo error. Since users can manipulate the chart as many times as they want they will most likely click on our reset button more than once.

Comment: edited again with 3rd option.  set the options as a separate variable first.  see link in answer

Comment: Option 3 is how I originally speced this out. It morphed into the version we use now because the chart is made in a code-behind and the js functions for controlling it are in the .ascx file - and therefor the vars are out of scope since they are both in their own document.ready block. I am now modifying the .ascx to make the chart and the chart options "global" vars but setting them in their same places.